# Unable to test methods in API Explorer - Security Header in not valid - 10002 error

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I logged into Paypal and created an Api user.

I now have an API signature, API username and API password.

When I go to https://devtools-paypal.com/apiexplorer/PayPalAPIs  API Explorer and enter my username, password and signature into the API cridentials field, I always get a "Security header is not valid - 10002" error.

The request body looks correct.  There are no spaces in my credentials and all the values are correct.

If I leave the default Paypal credentials in the API Credentials fields, the transactionSearch method works as expected.

How can I test this method in the API Explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that page can only call the Sandbox endpoint. Are you using Sandbox credentials or Live credentials?

Comment: You are correct, after further research I found my sandbox credentials and was able get the method to return successfully.

Now I am just having trouble creating personal sandbox users to generate test payments...

Hopefully the test account setup will work tomorrow.